# How do you handle answers or questions that are expired?

Tags: discussion

Some questions/ answers are outdated after a while. For example about when Homestead will be released etc. They are in a future form and now have already passed. Should one edit all the questions and answers or pick one answer and incorporate all facts and close the other answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If answers are outdated, create a new answers refecting more recent information. During the time, the best and most accurate answers will be voted on top.

If questions are attached to quickly changing events, they can be locked and preserved for historic reasons. But that's rarely the case.

A question like "*When will homestead be released?*" is not relevant anymore from a today's perspective, but I don't see a need to close or lock that thread, because the answer is still valid for users looking up on information "*When was homestead released?*"

One thing you could do is editing them to reflect the correct tense, e.g., *will be* becomes *was*. But in general it would avoid editing posts which changes their content or context.

If it is not accurate anymore, vote it down. If you know it better from a today's perspective, post a new answer.